# Postgres timeline simulator

Tags: performance, postgresql

I want to order search results by (age group, rank), and have age groups of 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 6 months etc. I know I can get the "days old" with

```
SELECT NOW()::DATE - created_at::DATE FROM blah
```

and am thinking to do a CASE statement based on that, but am I barking up the right tree performance wise?﻿ Is there a nicer way?

Comment: I'd probably use a `CASE` wrapped in a function, for convenience of re-use, but yeah, I think that's a reasonable approach. Please use `current_date` instead of `now()::date` though, the latter is just ugly, as well as nonstandard.

Comment: The raw CASE was surprisingly fast, but I've only got 27,000 records at the moment. The date ranges won't change very, so I've opted to have an extra "age_range INT" on the table and update it every so often. Now using current_date :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create separate table with intervals definition and labels. However this comes at cost of extra join to get the data.

```
create table distance (
  d_start int,
  d_end int,
  d_description varchar
);

insert into distance values
 (1,7,'1 week'),
 (8,30,'1 month'),
 (31,180,'6 months'),
 (181,365,'1 year'),
 (366,999999,'more than one year')
 ;

 with 

 sample_data as (
  select * 
  from generate_series('2013-01-01'::date,'2014-01-01'::date,'1 day') created_at
  )

select
  created_at,
  d_description
from
  sample_data sd
  join distance d on ((current_date-created_at::date) between d.d_start and d.d_end)
;
```

Comment: Will play with what you've written to see if it can be used for faster updates and more flexible date ranges. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using this function to update an INT column stored on the table for performance reasons,and running an occasional update task. What's nice that way is that it's only necessary to run it against a small subset of the data once per hour (anything <~ 1 week old), and every 24 hours can just run it against anything > 1 week old (perhaps even a weekly task for even older stuff.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION age_group(_date timestamp) RETURNS int AS
$$
DECLARE
  days_old int;
  age_group int;
BEGIN
  days_old := current_date - _date::DATE;
  age_group := CASE
    WHEN days_old < 2 THEN 0
    WHEN days_old < 8 THEN 1
    WHEN days_old < 30 THEN 2
    WHEN days_old < 90 THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END;
  RETURN age_group;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```